# Xamarin Forms Name error CS0103

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My login page XAML wont compile, the naming in its code behind is throwing an exception ( as below )[image: compile error with Login page]

Entry Username & Entry Password are the x:Name's from XAML of LoginPage.

I do not see how the same files code behind can error out, or is it to do with the Android & IOS compatibility. Need some clarification so i can rectify for future developments. Cheers in advance.

B

Comment: Check the `x:Class` attribute in the page XAML (in your case, probably `LoginPage.xaml`). Most likely, the name or the namespace of your code behind class `LoginPage.xaml.cs` is incorrect.

Comment: Can you please share Xaml code?

Comment: Thank you Ale, this helped me out every time I created a new project the same issue popped up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сheck your page login.xaml - x:Class attribute and root element.
This is the main reason why InitializeComponent not working.

Example: This is not working

```
 <ContentPage  --root control
    x:Class="Test.LoginPage" 

  namespace Test.Core.LoginPage
  {  
  public partial class LoginPage: Grid
```

This is working:

```
   <ContentPage  --root control
    x:Class="Test.LoginPage" 

  namespace Test.LoginPage
  {
  public partial class LoginPage: ContentPage
```